# Error occured generate scripts in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, generate-scripts

I generated scripts so many times in server db. I am maintaining two types of databases in single sql server. I got one error last week:

> Unhandled exception has occured in a component of your application..

I just don't care about this. Then I generate scripts in this database I got error like:

> Index was outside of the bounds of an array.

But I generated scripts in the same sql server with another database. It is generated successfully. I don't know is this technical error or not? Please help me what is going on?

Comment: you should probably post an example of your script and your schema. Difficult to solve problem otherwise.

Comment: i cant post script schema. i can post the screenshots. i edit question.

Comment: I've had this a couple of times and I guess it's just bugs in the Management Studio software, as it happens rarely, but randomly with different scripts - and never when I execute the scripts as Stored Procedures or from C#.

Comment: Even if your database is sql 2008 you can run management studio for sql server 2010 or 2012. That might be a solution? If not you would have to comment out parts of your script or delete rows in your table, until the error disappears. That way you might find out what is causing it and you can figgure out a workaround.